# react native: what is the error while i trying to navigate to some page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

what is the issue while i trying to navigate to some page ?
i try to navigate to some page but cant do it and i dont understand whats missing there ?

i add image of the error:
[image: this is the error]

this is my example :

```
<TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('PAGE9')}
        style={styles.button}
      >
        <Text style={styles.textButton}>MOVE ON</Text>
        <Image style={{ height: 60, width: 60 }} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Is 'PAGE9' defined on your stack navigation?

Comment: SURE IT IS.. the error talk about some params.list

Comment: Have you tried with this.props.navigation.navigate("PAGE9") ?

Comment: yes i did and it gives also error : "evaluating _this.props "

Comment: I don't see this error is related to navigation at all. in 'PAGE9' screen you are trying to use `params.list` wherein `params` is undefined and you are trying to access `list` attribute from `params`.

Comment: Please post the code from the component rendered on ```PAGE9``` route.

Comment: @SaachiTech can u help me in private please ? chat or something ?

Comment: The code you give doesn't seem to have anything to do with the error you give.  Can you show the code located at where it says the error occurred?

Comment: its long , can u talk in chat or something ?

Answer (score 0):

In PAGE9, or whichever component you are trying to render, you are making a reference to params.list - something like `{route.params.list}`
This can be done only if you passed a parameter which you probably didn't/forgot to do, and that's why its undefined.
Simply put, your error is the referencing/calling of an undefined value.